# Android P2P Wifi Direct / Bluetooth

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth, wifi, p2p

I am developing currently an Android application that will communicate with other Android devices per Wifi. The Wifi will also provide the online connection. There is no server in this Wifi environment.

The idea was that the devices will discover each other with UDP multicast messages. But we noticed that UDP multicast often does not work on the devices. Sometimes it does, sometimes not.

To work around this issue we implemented a mechanism where the devices will store the local Ips online so that other devices will be able to retrieve them.
But this, of course, does only work if the Online State is available, which sometimes is not.

My question is, if there are other techniques with what the devices are able to connect per Wifi to the each other without knowing it´s Ip in the first place. Is there an easy way to forward the addresses per Bluetooth for example? Or could Wifi Direct be an option?

Every idea is welcome. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

A [zero configuration networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) solution might work for you. There is a Nuget package called zeroconf that should work with Xamarin:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zeroconf/

Source code:
https://github.com/onovotny/Zeroconf